# When I touch with three fingers error is thrown in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-android

I have developed one app in react native and ready to publish , but at the end while testing when I touch app with three fingers it is giving error which does not look to user, I am not able to solve it.

[image]

Comment: any fix on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a temporary fix which worked for me

```
    import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';        
NativeModules.ExceptionsManager = null;
```